# Streamwriter is cutting off my last couple of lines sometimes in the middle of a line?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Here is my code. :

```
FileStream fileStreamRead = new FileStream(pathAndFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
FileStream fileStreamWrite = new FileStream(reProcessedFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStreamWrite);

                int readIndex = 0;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileStreamRead))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
                        Console.WriteLine("eof" + sr.EndOfStream);
                        readIndex++;
                        Console.WriteLine(readIndex);
                        string currentRecord = "";
                        currentRecord = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (currentRecord.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Writing " + readIndex);
                            sw.WriteLine(currentRecord);
                        }
                        else {
                            Console.WriteLine("*******************************************spaces ***********************");
                        }
                    }
```

It is cutting off 2 lines with one test file and half a line, and then 1 line and half a line with the other test file I am running it against.

I am not a streamreader/writer expert you can probably see.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me batty.  I am sure it is me using these incorrectly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are missing Flush/Close or simply `using` for your writer.

```
using(FileStream fileStreamWrite = 
  new FileStream(reProcessedFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
{
  using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStreamWrite))
  {
   // .... write everything here
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tigran - most Writer and Stream classes have internal buffers of limited size, so periodically they commit data to underlying storage. As result some data is stored, but last chunk could be lost if not flushed/closed.

Answer (score 11):

Right after the closing brace of the `using` statement, do this:

```
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

There, that should do it.

Comment: came across this answer, i had basically the same question.  For my situation, this helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Dispose() which calls Close() which calls Flush()

Answer (score 5):

You need to `Flush` your `StreamWriter`. A StreamWriter has a buffer, and it writes to disk only when the buffer is full. By flushing at the end you make sure all the text in the buffer is written to the disk.

Comment: @UserSmith, once after all writes, also missing using on Files (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers (use `using`, and/or `flush/close`), would say that they do not actually respond to the question: "why it may cut several lines."

I have an *idea* on subject that it is related to a fact that you use  `StreamReader` and call `EndOfStream` *twice*: in a `while` loop header, and another inside it.

The only possible way of understanding if the `stream` ends is **try** to read some data from it. So I suspect `EnfOfStream` does it, and reading it twice, may create a problem in stream processing.

To resolve an issue:

- Or use simple [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx), considering that you are reading text file (seems to me)
- Or change your logic to call only once, so no more call to `Console.WriteLine("eof" + sr.EndOfStream);`
- Or change your logic, so do not use `EndOFStream` at all, but read line by line till the line is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using StreamWriter properly.  Also, since you're always reading lines, I would use a method that already does all that for you (and manages it properly).

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path"))
{
   foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("path"))
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) 
       { /**/ }
       else
       { /**/ }
   }
}
```

... or ...

```
/* do not call .ToArray or something that will evaluate this _here_, let WriteAllLines do that */
var lines = File.ReadLines("path")
                .Select(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) ? Stars : line);

var encoding = Encoding.ASCII; // whatever is appropriate for you.
File.WriteAllLines("path", lines, encoding);
```